# In a C++ template class, can I typedef the template parameter using the same name?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

If I have a template class:

```c
template<typename Layout>
class LayoutHandler : Handler {
};
```

and I want to expose the parameter Layout to the user of the class.
Then:

```c
template<typename Layout>
class LayoutHandler : Handler {
public:
    typedef Layout Layout; // using the same name
};
```

VS2012 can compile this code, and give the expected result. (I use std::is_same to check it.)
Is this allowed in standard C++03 or C++11?

Comment: I'd guess it's allowed but would discourage that though (just doesn't feel good). I'd prefer s.th. like `typedef Layout LayoutType;` just for readability.

Comment: Personally I prefer using only one name for one thing. In constructors I also write something like T::T(int a): a(a)  {}

Comment: What's the purpose of `typedef` it with the same name? I dont quite get it.

Comment: @marson the purpose of the `typedef` is to make the template parameter type available to code outside of the class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not allowed in C++11.

A `typedef` is a declaration. (see section 7.1.3)

A `template` parameter can't be redeclared within its scope (including nested scopes). (see section 14.6.1.6)

[C++11 draft standard n3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

No till C+11 you can't use it, it gives you an error.

declaration of ‘typedef Layout LayoutHandler::Layout’
error:  shadows template parm ‘class Layout’

Comment: So does standard C++11 allow this?

Comment: "Till C++11 you can't use it" I don't think it works for C++11 either (at least for me).